# What is the best approach to add a method to a class in a flutter sdk?

Tags: flutter, dart, version-control

I want to add a new method to the Navigator Class in Flutter.

I can just go ahead and modify the file in the SDK but I wonder if there is a better approach that:

- Can be picked up by version control
- Is project-specific, The changes only apply to one specific project and other projects still get to use the vanilla Navigator class.

Comment: Hey @rayming~
Let me introduce you to a concept called inheritance: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class

Comment: Hello there @happy_san~ In my case inheritance is not a good option because the rest of the SDK depends on the Navigator class. If I were to create a new class inherited from the Navigator class, I'll have to modify other classes in the SDK to make sure they use my new class instead of the navigator class. That would produce more work for me

Comment: You'll probably want to use extension methods. https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

Comment: Hi @Stephen~ I gave it a try but run into some problems. To implement the method I have in mind I need to access some private classes that exist in "navigator.dart" file. I can't get access to those classes from anywhere else unless I'm modifying the file itself. Is there another way?

Comment: It would help if you described exactly what you want to do (instead of falling into the trap of the X-Y problem).  If you must modify the `Navigator` code, it would be better in the long run to make an upstream contribution if it is something that would be useful to others.  Alternatively, you can simply fork the classes you need.